# how to replicate an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to make a function like this

```
>> matdup([1 2],3,4)            %or any other input that user wish to enter
ans= 

 1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2
 1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2
 1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2
```

I am stuck in my code. My logic:

```
m = matdup(input,row,col)
for i = 1:row
        for j = 1:col
            m(i, j)= input;
```

This is producing this:

```
>> matdup(1,2,2)
ans=

      1 1
      1 1
```

But failed at this:

```
>> matdup([1 2],3,4)
```

error at console:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

    Error in ==> matdup at 6
                m(i, j)= input
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab has a funcion called [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) that does the same.

If you want to create a similar function, you could do something like this:

```
function B = matdup(A, M, N)
    [nr, nc] = size(A);
    B = zeros([nr nc] .* [M N]);
    for r = 1:M
        for c = 1:N
            rr = (r - 1) * nr + 1;
            cc = (c - 1) * nc + 1;
            B(rr:rr + nr - 1, cc:cc + nc - 1) = A;
        end
    end
end
```

Note this function is restricted to 2D matrices.

Comment: i am not allowed to do so. any other thing. i ve idea but not convinced for example taking the size and implementing. but i cant think further what to do next. is it possible to look at library how they have made function?

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:** Are you allowed to use `ones`? Try this -

```
A = [1 2]

rowIdx = [1 : size(A,1)]';
colIdx = [1 : size(A,2)]';

out = A(rowIdx(:, ones(3,1)), colIdx(:, ones(4,1)))
```

**Output**

```
out =

     1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2
     1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2
     1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2
```

**Method 2:** Are you allowed to use `bsxfun` and `permute`? Try this for the same result -

```
A = [1 2]
row_mapped = bsxfun(@plus,A,zeros(3,1))
out = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,row_mapped,permute(zeros(4,1),[3 2 1])),[3 8])
```

Comment: @user3440716 Added one more method!

Answer (score 2):

Try `kron`:

```
matdup = @(x,m,n) kron(ones(m,n),x)
```

Demonstration:

```
>> A = [5 6 7];
>> out = matdup(A,3,2)
out =
     5     6     7     5     6     7
     5     6     7     5     6     7
     5     6     7     5     6     7
```

---

Note that you can switch the inputs to `kron` to effectively replicate elements rather than the whole matrix:

```
repel = @(x,m,n) kron(x,ones(m,n));
```

Demonstration:

```
>> A = [5 6 7];
>> out = repel(A,3,2)
out =
     5     5     6     6     7     7
     5     5     6     6     7     7
     5     5     6     6     7     7
```

Answer (score 2):

The replication can be done easily using [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mod.html):

```
function R = matdup(A, M, N)
    [m n]= size(A);
    R = A(mod(0:m*M-1,m)+1, mod(0:n*N-1,n)+1)
```

Comment: Clever way to generate steps at a certain period. +1