# pre-defined array elements in from single line of code matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

How to create a pre-defined array elements in from single line of code, i.e I have followings array sequence, how can I generate this via a single line of code, as I want to input that to the function argument. It have always the sequence of `0010` and also, 4 columns and 24 rows.

I tried the following:

```
[0 0 0 1 :24]
```

The output I want:

```
                          [ 0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0,
                          0 0 1  0 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)  to replicate the data column-wise to create multiple rows -

```
repmat([0 0 1 0],24,1)
```

Look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847086/how-to-replicate-an-array) for more ways to replicate data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use matrix multiplication

```
ones( 24, 1 ) * [0 0 1 0]
```

Using `tic`-`toc` this method seems to be faster than `repmat` (on my machine):

```
tic; 
for ii=1:100000, 
    repmat( [0 0 1 0], 24, 1 );
end;
toc, 
tic, 
for ii=1:100000, 
    ones(24,1)*[0 0 1 0];
end;
toc
```

And the results are

> Elapsed time is `1.090915` seconds.  // @[Divakar's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22893026/1714410) using `repmat`
>   Elapsed time is `0.163920` seconds.   // using matrix multiplication