# concatenating matrices a variable number of times in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I write this is one command in Matlab (or without loop)

```
X=A;
for i =1:d-1
    X= cat(3, X, A);
end
```

I tried to use permute, and then repmat, but the singleton last dimension is eliminated automatically, so that does not help.

Comment: `X = repmat(A,[1 1 d])` Look for more ways to replicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847086/how-to-replicate-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the repmat function (see [repmat doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html))

```
X = repmat(A, [size(A), d])
```