# Creating a meshgrid, without mesh command

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create an array that looks like this (as an example)

```
X = | 1 2 3 |
    | 1 2 3 |
    | 1 2 3 |

Y = | 1 1 1 |
    | 2 2 2 |
    | 3 3 3 |
```

I tried doing a nested for loop *inside* a while loop, with this method, the Y array works but not the X array, I sort of understand why its not working but I dont know how to fix it.

this is what I got

```
X = [];
Y = [];
c=1;


while c<=3;

    for i=1:3

        for j=1:3
            X(i,c)=j;
            Y(i,c)=i;
        end
    end
    c=c+1;
end
```

I understand that the meshgrid command will do this for me with one line of code, but I have to do it with a nested for loop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Without any matlab command or just meshgrid ?

Comment: sorry! but i just figured it out, how to do it, cheers

Comment: You are basically trying to replicate data, for which you can follow the solutions to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847086/how-to-replicate-an-array or just use `repmat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this :

```
startIter = 1;
endIter = 3;

X = [];
Y = [];

line = startIter:endIter 

for i = 1:endIter    
    X = [X;line];
    Y = [Y,line'];    
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Oops! Just noticed you wanted to do this with a `for` loop.  I apologize.  As such, I'll just leave this here as reference in case anyone wants to know how to do this without a loop.

---

You can do this without any `for` loops at all.  Try using `repmat`.

```
x = 1 : 3;
y = (1 : 3)';

X = repmat(x, 3, 1);
Y = repmat(y, 1, 3);
```

Result:

```
X =

 1     2     3
 1     2     3
 1     2     3


Y =

 1     1     1
 2     2     2
 3     3     3
```

In general, if you want an `M x N` matrix, do the following:

```
x = 1 : N
y = (1 : M)';

X = repmat(x, M, 1);
Y = repmat(y, 1, N);
```

### Aside

If by off chance you're **not** allowed to use `repmat` you can replicate data by specifying an array of *ones* in the dimension you want.  However, this becomes very slow when the size of the matrix becomes large so care must be taken here.

```
x = 1 : N;
y = (1 : M)';

X = x(ones(M, 1), :);
Y = y(:, ones(N, 1));
```

Comment: I Like the Aside version, I never saw that one before. It cool, but poor performance right. I like the repmat too, but Matlab is really optimize for matrix indexing and concat and other thing like that.