# Alternative of repmat for large vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I am writing a code in which the speed and time reduction is really important. I have to create some matrices by repeating some vectors. As my vectors are almost large, using repmat to create these matrices takes relatively a long time. Is there any other way to reduce this time?

Comment: See if this is inspiring enough - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847086/how-to-replicate-an-array

Comment: why do you need to replicate these vectors in the first place? maybe you can avoid this replication altogether by using `bsxfun`?

Comment: Though I don't exclude the possiblity of beating repmat, it is not that bad. As such you will probably want to look into creation AND use of your matrices.

Comment: @Shai in my computation i need to do such thing, by the way, actually i don't know what is bsxfun and how it works

Comment: @user3482383 please look at matlab's help on [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/bsxfun.html). You can also see some examples at [tag:bsxfun] tag wiki.

Comment: If you really see `repmat` show up as the bottleneck in the profiler, the only explanations I can give for that are 1) your vector contains user-implemented types that are deep-copied by `repmat`, 2) you run out of memory and MATLAB is paging to the harddrive, in which case `bsxfun` and friends could come in handy (or implementing implicit replication yourself somehow). `repmat` is pretty efficient, and I have strong doubts that it is the real bottleneck.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis i checked the profreport for the code and it says that the time consuming one is repmat, maybe because my vectors are large, they have almost 1500 elements. is it why it does like this?

Comment: @user3482383: so what do you need the replicated matrices for?

Comment: the data which have to be imported into my computation has this form, i mean it is a replication of a vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our test vector:

```
V0 = [1; 2; 3];
```

Tony's trick:

```
V1 = V0(:, ones(3,1))
```

Matrix/vector multiplication:

```
V2 = V0 * ones(1,3);
```

Kronecker product:

```
V3 = kron(V0, ones(1,3))
```

Concatenation:

```
V4 = [V0 V0 V0]
```

Inobvious way:

```
V5 = arrayfun(@(~)V0, 1:3, 'uniformoutput', false);
V5 = cat(2, V5{:});
```

The least obvious way:

```
[Vi{1:3}] = deal(V0);
V6 = [Vi{:}]
```

Use `repmat` from the [Lightspeed toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/2135-the-lightspeed-matlab-toolbox).

Or, the best way, use implicit expansion (R2008 and up):

```
%# NOTE: this PREVENTS having to do explicit replication, and carries 
%# out the multiplication re-using the same elements from V0: 
M = bsxfun(@times, rand(1,5), V0)
```

Comment: For the last one I would expect `ones(1,5)` or `ones(3,5)`. Small sidenote for the asker: perhaps not all of these methods will turn out to be faster than repmat.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: the last one is to show that you don't need the explicitly replicated vector, but that you can carry out any multiplication/addition/etc. with implicit replication. Therefore, I named the output `M` and not `V7` :)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Also, you are right :) `repmat` is pretty fast, and the implementation in the lightspeed toolbox loses out for modern MATLAB, except in a few hardly-ever encountered niche cases. And even then it's hardly ever the bottleneck. I suspect the OP has a whole different problem altogether. I was just having fun trying to come up with more ways to do it :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis  if i could do the repmat thing on smaller vectors but more times, is there any difference in time?

Comment: +1 You need to change the `arrayfun` line to `V5 = arrayfun(@(~)V0, 1:3, 'uniformoutput', 0);`